# Simple sqlite3_prepare issue in objective c

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I've read various tutorials online about dealing with sqlite3 databases in ios, in particular I've read through a "Ray Wenderlich" tutorial and read through many queries on here, but I just cannot see why my code doesn't work.

I have a simple database that appears to open perfectly well. It has a table in with 200 multiple choice questions. I'm trying to select all the answers, the query is not complex, and it works in sqlitebrowser.

I've added `libsqlite3.dylib` to the project too, otherwise the opening of the database wouldn't work. I'm sure that this is a really simple fix but I just can't see it after staring at the code:

```
@implementation QuizController
sqlite3 *db;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSLog(@"Hello Quiz");

  NSString *p = [self filePath];
  [self openDB];
  NSString *query = @"SELECT answer from questions";

  sqlite3_stmt *statement;

  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)
    == SQLITE_OK) {

    NSLog(@"SQLITE PREPARED OK!");
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        NSLog(@"YES");

    }
  }
  else{
    NSLog(@"sqlite prepare failed");
  }


}


//file path to db
-(NSString *) filePath {
  NSLog(@"pathtest");
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"questionsDb.sqlite"];
}

//open the db
-(void)openDB {
  NSLog(@"opentest");
  if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) !=SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"%d", sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSLog(@"Database failed to open");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"database opened");
  }
}
```

The log output that I see is:

```
2014-10-16 20:52:01.627 QuizTemplate[15963:802498] pathtest
2014-10-16 20:52:01.627 QuizTemplate[15963:802498] opentest
2014-10-16 20:52:01.628 QuizTemplate[15963:802498] pathtest
2014-10-16 20:52:01.648 QuizTemplate[15963:802498] database opened
2014-10-16 20:52:01.649 QuizTemplate[15963:802498] sqlite prepare failed
```

Comment: What is your target OS?

Comment: Observe the pretty good documents at sqlite.org.  In particular, observe the [`sqlite3_errmsg`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) function.  Use it religiously.  (And don't attempt the open again just to get the return code -- save it off the first attempt.)

Comment: BTW - Do you realize that your `db` variable is declared as a global and not as an instance variable. That is most likely not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Change your "sqlite prepare failed" to include `sqlite3_errmsg`:

```
NSLog(@"sqlite prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
```

It will undoubtedly tell you that the table doesn't exist.

This is because your open routine is just opening the database in the documents folder and if it's not there, it will create a blank database. (That's what `sqlite3_open` does if there is no file found.)

You presumably want to:

1. Uninstall the app from your device/simulator in order to delete any blank database that might have been there.
2. You want to call a routine that will look for the database in documents, and if not found, copy it from the bundle to Documents:

   ```
   - (void) installDatabaseIfNeeded {

       // Get the documents database path

       NSString *documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
       NSString *documentsDatabasePath = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite"]; // always use setter when setting property's value

       NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

       if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentsDatabasePath]) {

           // if the database doesn't exist in documents, look for it in the bundle and copy it if found

           NSString *bundleDatabasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"sqlite"];

           if (bundleDatabasePath) {
               NSError *error;
               if (![fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundleDatabasePath toPath:documentsDatabasePath error:&error]) {
                   NSLog(@"copyItemAtPath failed: %@", error);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Clearly, change the filename referenced in the `bundleDatabasePath` and `documentsDatabasePath`, but hopefully this illustrates the concept.

---

If you're still having problems, a couple of additional thoughts:

1. Replace all of your calls to `sqlite3_open` with `sqlite3_open_v2` with the `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` option. If we omit the `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` option, it will obviously not  create blank database if it doesn't find it. Let's just eliminate that possibility. Thus:

   ```
   - (void)openDB {
       NSLog(@"opentest");
       int rc = sqlite3_open_v2([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
       if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
           NSLog(@"open failed: %d", rc);
           NSLog(@"Database failed to open");
       } else {
           NSLog(@"database opened");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Again, delete the app and reinstall it. (Don't just do a "clean build", but actually remove the app from the device/simulator.)
3. Build the app and install it on your simulator. Now check the database in the bundle:

   - Open up the simulator's device folder;
   - Find your app in the Mac OS file system (underneath `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` in Xcode versions prior to 6, `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` in Xcode 6);
   - Open up the application's bundle (right click on it and choose "Show package contents");
   - Find the database copy in the bundle; and
   - Open it up in your database tool of choice. Make sure your table is actually there in that copy of the database and that the name is right.

   Sometimes Xcode can get confused about what's in the bundle (notably, with externally edited files, like SQLite databases), which can be resolved by deleting the derived data folder. Or perhaps you have multiple copies of your database and neglected to update the one in your Xcode project.

   It could be a ton of things, so by examining what's really in the bundle, it will identify the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, you were indeed correct, I got a message saying the table doesn't exist. However, I added your function - and changed the filename appropriately - and called it before opening the DB, but I still got the same message. This was done on a fresh emulator BTW.

Comment: @Kells1986 See revised answer with a few more suggestions. BTW, this is a _very_ common SQLite problem, but it will just take some sleuthing to identify precisely where it's gone wrong.